# Django(not rest-framework) don`t remember the sessions if a make multiple request from react app

Tags: reactjs, django

I trying to make request from react-app(http://localhost:8082/) to django-app(not rest-framework) and after each request , request.session.items() is empty.
This is happend only when i make requests from browsers , if makes all this steps from postman the sessions middleware works good.
I think the problem is from Headers , but i don`t find it

React requests :

```
var qs = require('qs');
const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'withCredentials':false,
'X-CSRF-TOKEN':'cwE9Ddste5nblT6ADjyi1AVhyyh4bQVirjr7CKiC3e5Fazw0YpwLmAQLFuu1X315'
}
axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/setSession',headers)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data);
    },(error) => {

    });
axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/getSession',headers)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data);
    },(error) => {

    });
```

Python views.py methods :

```
#@csrf_exempt
def setSession(request):
    request.session['id'] = 12312312
    request.session['token'] = 'test'
    return JsonResponse({'status':200},safe=False,status=202)

#@is_auth
#@csrf_exempt
def getSession(request):
    print(request.session.items());
    return JsonResponse({'status':200},safe=False)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3Sbp.png)

Comment: JS is async by design. Add the getSession call to the then() block of setSession and try again.

Comment: Hi, Thanks but that not solve the problem.